# Trinity Desktop Environment on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

Is it possible / does anybody have experience with installing the Trinity Desktop Environment (TDE) on a preexisting Linux Mint 17 Qiana installation?

The TDE developers have a Wiki entry for installing it on Ubuntu. Maybe this can be recycled?

PS: I use the Xfce edition.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?